# Mysql user feed with large amount of posts

Tags: mysql, bigdata

I have three mysql tables:

[image]

1. users - Contains user details
2. posts - Contains post details
3. post_user - Contains which post should each user access (for read purposes)

I really need the pivot table since there is a lot of logic that decides if the user can/cannot read the post.

There are some problems with this solution:

1. The first problem is that I have 200k+ active users so every time a new post is created 200k rows are inserted to the pivot table (post_user)
2. Second problem is when fetching the posts for each user. it is a bit slow so I tried using Redis for storing the result of the query for each user so I don't have to fetch the result from that huge table.
3. The DB size is growing extremely fast :/

Comment: "Pivot" is really the wrong terminology here. Generally "Connector" or "Relationship" table is used. Pivot is more of a functionality where in row values are pivotted into column headers and other fields are aggregated in some way under the new header values.

Comment: i don't understand why the table `post_user` is acting as a "privilege" table. Besides all users have defualt read "privilege" to all posts wouldn't it  be better to create a blacklist table where you "ban" some users to a post? That would require less database space.

Comment: As for this as a solution I agree it seems like a really bad design. A user shouldn't gain access to a post like this. Instead consider creating a `role` table that holds roles a user may be in (One might be "Read all posts"). Then a `user_role` table for the mapping. You can get deeper by create a `perm` table and a `role_perm` table so that `user` is mapped to a `role` and a `role` has `permissions` one of which might be "Read all Posts". Then update your code accordingly.

Comment: [Here's a great article about "Role Based Access Control"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control) which would really help you gain control over this. There's also libraries out there in many languages that implement this logic so you don't have roll your own.

Comment: OP should clarify whether he needs the fine-grain control of having individual permissions for each user, in which case a role based approach is pointless. Seems like you all assume this is not the case.

Comment: The reason I chose this option is because the db is designed for the scouts organization so when a user writes a post it should reach only the users that are under his hierarchical tree, in addition the user that writes the post can choose to which of his hierarchical branches he want to reach. So thats why a simple role system is not enough for this case

Comment: That bit if info is really important and should be in your question. Each user could be assigned to a "group" (IOW troup, etc). The groups would be stored in a table of organizations in a tree. Then it's a simple query to determine which posts a user can read.

Answer (score 0):

Adding 200K rows for each `post` -- Yikes!  That alone is a sign of a bad design.

Sounds like the ids of "hierarchical trees" could function as a "roles" or "group".

Regardless of what it is called, the implementation is the same:  Two relationship tables:

- user <-> group (eg, which part of the tree a user is in)
- group <-> post (which group(s) can read a specific post)

Both are many:many, and should be implemented using the guidelines [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) for performance.  Note that `id` (for a mapping table) is useless and likely to get in the way of performance.